# SQLPlus Trailing Whitespace Issues

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

My script is spooling the output of some queries to a text file.

```
set linesize 200
set trimspool on
....

spool "C:\someFile.txt"
SELECT rpad(field1, 50)||rpad(field2, 50) FROM table1;
SELECT rpad(field3, 200) FROM table2;
spool off
```

What I want is for every row output in query 1 to be 100 characters including trailing whitespace, and for every row output in query 2 to be 200 characters including trailing whitespace.

If `trimspool` is off, then every line has 200 characters, which is not what I want.  If it is on, then in the case that field3 is only 10 characters long, the length of that line in the output file is only 60 characters (it needs to be 100).  Each line needs to be fixed length because the file will be sent to an external server and is going parsed based on the assumption that it is fixed length.

Is there any way to avoid trimming the whitespace that I explicitly output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
set trimspool off
spool "C:\someFile.txt"
set linesize 100
SELECT rpad(field1, 50)||rpad(field2, 50) FROM table1;
set linesize 200
SELECT rpad(field3, 200) FROM table2;
spool off
```

The output includes the commands themselves, so if you want to get rid of those and include only the query results, put all the commands in a script file and just execute the script file. Also add these to the top of the script:

```
set echo off
set termout off
set pagesize 0
set feedback off
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  I didn't know that you could use `set` throughout like that.  There's one situation where it won't work for me though: `SELECT CASE WHEN field1=1 THEN rpad(field2, 50) ELSE rpad(field3, 200) END FROM table1`.  Do you know if it's possible to get something working for that query, so that the lines are either 50 or 200 chars and not always 200?

Comment: I don't know of any way to alternate the width from one record to the next. The basic problem is that `SELECT` is an Oracle command and `SET LINESIZE` is SQL*Plus command. While the `SELECT` is going on in "Oracle world" you can't reach out to "SQL*Plus" world to switch the line sizes. If you can't live with trimmed rows or one set of length 100 followed by one set of length 200 then you'll need a new approach, such as messing with the file afterward, or writing a stored procedure that uses the `UTL_File` library, or a C/Java/C#/PHP/whatever program that will query and write.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought.  No harm in asking.